# Fedora 25 LiveUSB can't boot on Dell XPS 13 (9343)

Tags: fedora, live-usb, unetbootin

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9343) and I would like to try Fedora 25 from live USB.

I prepared the USB drive using unetbootbin on Ubuntu using this file: `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso` (if I prepare the drive with `Disks` it is not recognized as UEFI bootable).

I rebooted, selected the USB drive to boot from (UEFI secure), and I got the Fedora boot menu. I edited the grub params and removed the `quiet` flag to see what was going on. I got the following screen (I got the last message when I removed the pendrive - so the kernel was not totally dead!).

The only thing I can do at this point is turn off the computer.

[image]

What is wrong and how do I fix it? I'm surprised because Ubuntu works without hiccups and Fedora 25 on the XPS 13 is reported to be working fine by other users.

PS. In the normal Ubuntu boot, the next message after the matching `clocksource` line in `dmesg` comes from `systemd`:

```
[    3.207740] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    8.053957] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.732566] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    8.732673] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
```

Comment: Please post a better-quality photo.

Comment: Photo replaced.

Comment: hmm, this is odd but unetbootin is not a recommended method.  I have prepared a drive using dd - equivalent to Disks - and it worked on UEFI secure boot Dell Lattitude E5450.  Disks is definitely supposed to work.  I have a suspicion you used Disks to write to the _partition_, instead of the _disk_. Did you use the "hamburger" menu button, at the top right of the Disks window, next to the window close button? That's what you want to write to the disk as a whole.  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-preparing-boot-media.html

Comment: Not downvoted despite disregarding the install guide (research), because you provided good specific information without needing to be prompted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, unetbootin is not a recommended method. It is mentioned by name as not being supported, in the [Fedora install guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-preparing-boot-media.html).

Disks is definitely expected to work, <del>although the install guide doesn't mention it either way</del> it is described in Proceedure 3.6 of the current install guide. I have a suspicion you used Disks to write to the partition, instead of the disk. Did you use the "hamburger" menu button, at the top right of the Disks window, next to the window close button? That's what you want to write to the disk as a whole.

The documented methods either use `dd`, or the Fedora Media Writer app.
I have prepared a drive using dd - this is equivalent to Disks - and it worked on UEFI secure boot Dell Latitude E5450.

I highly recommend reading the installation guide for your chosen operating system when encountering such difficulties.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-preparing-boot-media.html

Comment: Restoring the image as a whole disk (as opposed to a partition) solved the boot issue. In my defence, nothing in the boot process indicates that there is a problem with the boot media, the kernel loads and starts as if everything was perfect. Also, there is no Fedora Media Writer for Ubuntu, and Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator only works with Ubuntu images. `dd` should have worked, obviously, I'm just shocked that in 2017 the average user is expected to use a low level command line tool for something like this. Ok, enough ranting, back to testing Wayland under Fedora!

Comment: oops, the install guide _does_ mention Disks and give correct instructions.  Have fun with Wayland :).

Comment: I also occurred this, live usb disk stop running after grub. My usb disk works well on my old xps 14, but not on an new xps 13 with high resolution screen. **unetbootin** is good to help keep my 3 partitions in usb disk so I choose it. **gnome-disks** only make the usb disk not boot. I know dd sure work, but say to dd, I think it would mess up my partitions' structure.